# Creating a stored procedure that accepts and computes the total salaries for that department and displays both the department # & the total salaries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What am I doing wrong here?

> Create a procedure that accepts a department number, computes the total basic salaries for that department, and displays both the department number and the total basic salaries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEPT_TOTAL_SALARY AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENTS_ID, SUM(SALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARIES
   FROM EMPLOYEES, DEPARTMENTS
   WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (‘*** TOTAL SALARY CALCULATED ***’);
END;
/
```

> Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> 4. FROM EMPLOYEES, DEPARTMENTS
> 5. WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
> 6. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('*** TOTAL SALARY CALCULATED ***');
> 7. END;
> 8. /

```
Table:  EMPLOYEES                           
    EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME   JOB_ID  JOB_DESCRIPTION HOD HIREDATE    SALARY  DEPARTMENT_ID
              1        SMITH        J1         CLERK    5   17-Dec-07    5,800.00   20
              2        ALLEN        J2      SLAESMAN    3   20-Feb-08    7,600.00   30
              3         WARD        J2      SALESMAN    5   22-Feb-08    8,250.00   30
              4        JONES        J3       MANAGER    7   2-Apr-08     4,900.00   20
              5         JACK        J2      SALESMAN    7   28-Sep-08    6,700.00   10
              6        BLAKE        J3       MANAGER    7   1-May-08     12,850.00  30
              7        CLARK        J3       MANAGER   NULL 9-Jun-08     22,450.00  10
              8        SCOTT        J4       ANALYST    5   9-Dec-08     13,000.00  20
              9       TURNER        J2      SALESMAN    3   8-Sep-07     5,500.00   30
             10        ADAMS        J1         CLERK    5   12-Jan-07    9,100.00   20
Table:  DEPARTMENTS     
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME LOCATION
          10    ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
          20    PRODUCTION  MINNESOTA
          50    SALES   CHICAGO
          40    OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

> Will the query code below execute the following if the DeptNum is 30? If not, how can I write a code to calculate all the salary of each department according to the EMPLOYEES table above?

```
 DeptNum    Total_Salary
--------    ------------
      30     34,200.00
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Dept_Total_Salary (deptNum NUMBER)
        AS
          total_salary NUMBER(12, 2);
        BEGIN
          SELECT SUM(Salary)
            INTO total_salary
            FROM Employees
            WHERE Department_ID = deptNum;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department ' || deptNum || ' salary is ' || total_salary);
        END;
```

Comment: The Oracle documentation might help here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm  I am not exactly sure but it may be that the above code is missing a parameter for department_ID as in: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEPT_TOTAL_SALARY (department_id NUMBER) AS...

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I see at least four errors, but there's not enough information here to give you an answer. Please post the structures of both tables, and indicate which table/column holds the department number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The salary and the department number are both in the `EMPLOYEES` table, so there's no need to include the `DEPARTMENTS` table in your query.

The errors in your query are:

1. You're not accepting the department number as a parameter to the stored procedure.
2. You're including the `DEPARTMENTS` table when you don't have to.
3. You're not filtering by department number with a `WHERE` clause.
4. You need to select the total salary into a variable to print it.
5. You need a semicolon after the `SELECT` query.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Dept_Total_Salary (deptNum NUMBER)
AS
  total_salary NUMBER(12, 2);
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(Salary)
    INTO total_salary
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Department_ID = deptNum;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department ' || deptNum || ' salary is ' || total_salary);
END;
```

---

Edit: forgot the semicolon after `END`, and right after I'd pointed out how you missed a semicolon - ouch!

Comment: WOW!!!! Your explanation is so thorough, and it is very easy to understand. Thank you very much. I realized I didn't needed the DEPARTMENTS table after I posted it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't execute properly. It works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> accepts a department number

The first thing you're doing wrong is ignoring this aspect of the requirements. You need to write a procedure that takes a department number and uses a `where` clause to limit what you retrieve from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this.

```
CREATE TABLE proTable -- create new table to store sum of sal for each dept
    (deptno NUMBER,
    sumSal NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE display_dept_sal_sum (v_deptno NUMBER)
AS 
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO proTable (deptno,SumSal)
        SELECT v_deptno,SUM(sal) 
        FROM employees 
        WHERE deptno = v_deptno;
END;

EXECUTE  display_dept_sal_sum(40);
SELECT * FROM proTable;
```